# openStream takes a long time to download a file

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, download

I have a web application that tries to download a file from another webapp.

When my webapp is run loaclly, the download from the other webapp (deployed in a tomcat6 server) is very fast.
Then when I deploy my webapp (in the same server), the download of the same file takes a long time (several minutes).

The code I use is this one:

```
response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=fileName"
response.contentType = 'application/zip'
response.outputStream << new URL(address).openStream()
response.outputStream.flush()
```

I cannot explain this difference, and I don't know if the problem comes from my webapp or from the server.

Comment: by "deploy my webapp` you mean `> grails run-war` ?

Comment: yes, I generate the war then I deploy it in the server

Comment: I'd say, use `HttpBuilder` to get the remote file. It gives you more control and you can trace what and how is being downloaded. `url.openStream()` is good for simple scripts

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is grails is trying to load all the file to memory. try this:

```
    new URL(address).withInputStream { response.outputStream << it }
```